# Is a shared list between multiple threads a race condition?

Tags: multithreading, multicore, openmp

I've got some multi threaded code that typically runs great, but every so often it will break. I'm trying to pinpoint the problem, but using OpenMP is making that more difficult (the problem does not occur in serial). I know that multiple access to a variable (race conditions) often crashes a program.

I've got a list shared between the multiple threads, and I'm curious if the push_back() on that list is a candidate for a race condition, therefore crashing my program every once in a while? If so, are there any recommendation on how to handle this?
- Speed is of the utmost importance
- I know that using `#pragma omp critical` would solve a race condition, but potentially slow down the application (there are two lists, so I need a critical rather than atomic).

The only reason I'm not sure about this is because I ran a couple tests, using stl containers, but never got the test code to crash.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about OpenMP specifically. However I can say that yes, two threads doing push_back (or any other modifying operation) on a list at the same time will cause problems, just the same as for a single variable.

I don't know what tools OpenMP gives you for protecting against this. Some common approaches to avoiding this problem:

1. Put a lock (eg a mutex) around operations on the variable.
2. Give each thread its own copy of the list, and have them remain independent. At the end of the process, as a separate step, you can merge the results from the different threads. (This is Map-Reduce, pretty much).

The second approach can give better results if you have many threads, and if it fits with your algorithm. Some algorithms can't be structured that way.

If you don't have many threads, depending on the size of your loop body, a simple lock might be the most effective solution.

Comment: If I'm only spawning as many threads as cores on my machine, four at the moment, I assume that isn't enough threads to make the merge of the stl container worth while?... thanks for the input!

Comment: @Brett I would guess not, although it also depends on how much work you're doing in the loop per item pushed. I would go with the simple lock solution, then measure, and if it's too slow look at other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using the lock, and it appears it rarely triggers it (hence why my program ran so many times between crashes). So I think it would only cost more time by utilizing separate data structures and combining them in the end.

Comment: agree this is the right solution. If you are using visual studio 2010 (or Intel TBB) you can use the template class combinable to use this e.g. a combinable<list<int>> for example which will give you a thread local list.  then you can use the combine_each method to 'splice' them together.

Comment: @Rick sweet, I hadn't come across that. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

STL containers are not intrinsically thread-safe.  You need to protect access to them using a synchronization mechanism.  The typical ones could be a semaphore or a mutex, with the mutex being in general the faster of the two.